# How to remove websites from gravatar profile

Tags: web, gravatar

I have created my gravatar profile and added websites from websites tab.
Now I want to delete some of my websites but I can't.
Please see the attached screenshot.[image]
when I click on delete button on left of the website, it removes from the list but when I again come to my website page, it remains the same.
Please help me remove unwanted websites from my profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gravatar information (as most of the content on large web sites, also the content on Wordpress.org/.com) is cached.

It *may* take a while the information to be refreshed. However this is not Wordpress specific question, if you experience the issue after a while (usualy a couple of hours), consult the gravatar FAQ/support.

Comment: I have checked FAQ on gravatar but there is no question related to this issue. Let me wait for few hours as you said and will tell you if it has been resolved or not.